# How to efficiently find frequencies in many-to-many relationships

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am building a data base to store how many times a person ordered a certain item.
This is a many-to-many relationship however I was wondering how I can effetely store the frequencies of how many times a customer ordered a certain item. Is my only option a count and group by statement or can I rearrange my database?

My Tables Look Like This Right Now:

Customer Table:

| Customer ID | Customer Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice |
| 2 | Bob |
| 3 | Eve |

Item Table:

| Item ID | Item Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Speaker |
| 2 | Keyboard |
| 3 | Mouse |

Items Bought

| Customer ID | Item ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |

So I am more interested in knowing that Customer 1 bought 2 of item 1, 2 of item 2 and 0 of item 3 more efficiently.

Comment: More efficiently than *what*?

Comment: Read about `GROUP_CONCAT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: How many rows do you anticipate in each table?

Answer (score 0):

If that's about the detail you have. You could always introduce another field to hold the quantity of the bought item. As in:

```
ALTER TABLE item_bought ADD COLUMN Count INTEGER NOT NULL;
```

And update that table using the query:

```
INSERT INTO item_bought (CustomerId, ItemId, Count)
VALUES (@var_customer_id, @var_item_id, @var_count)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE -- assuming CustomerId, ItemId is unique key
  Count := Count + @var_count
;
```

and select it like:

```
SELECT CustomerId, ItemId, Count
FROM item_bought
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table design is fine and you probably want to add more information, such as the purchase date to the items_bought table, if you haven't done so already.

In order to know how many times customer #1 bought the items you need

```
select i.item_id, count(ib.item_id)
from item i
left join items_bought ib on ib.item_id = i.item_id and ib.customer_id = 1
group by i.item_id
order by i.item_id;
```

You want an index on items_bought for this. I'd try the following two, see which is being used by the DBMS and drop the other:

```
create index idx1 on items_bought (item_id, customer_id);
create index idx2 on items_bought (customer_id, item_id);
```

It would be more convenient though to have a table that already contains the desired data. This is a data warehouse approach. You'd add a table

```
dwh_customer_item (customer_id, item_id, amount)
```

with a primary key on `customer_id, item_id`. Then add a trigger that adds rows whenever an item is added to the database, adding these rows:

```
insert into dwh_customer_item (customer_id, item_id, amount)
 select c.customer_id, new.item_id, 0 as amount from customer c;
```

and a trigger that adds rows whenever a customer is added to the database, adding these rows:

```
insert into dwh_customer_item (customer_id, item_id, amount)
 select new.customer_id, i.item_id, 0 as amount from item i;
```

At last a trigger to increase the amount on every insert into items_bought adding these rows:

```
update dwh_customer_item
set amount = amount + 1
where customer_id = new.customer_id
and item_id = new.item_id;
```

With such a concept you can even delete old rows from items_bought without losing the total count.

It is your choice though, if you want all this added to your database. The original tables are fine and the query (an appropriate index provided) would be very fast already.